# Global variable definition in C

Tags: c, global-variables

In my code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a;
a=3;

void main(){
printf("%d",a);
}
```

Why am I getting the warning,

```
a.c:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
```

In another case, when I have

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int* a;
a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

void main(){
*a=3;
printf("%d",a);
}
```

I get `error: conflicting types for ‘a’`, and also warning as

`warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only initialise global variables with constants and it has to be done during the declaration:

```
 int a = 3; // is valid
```

If you need to initialise a global variable with the return of `malloc` then that has to happen during runtime.

```
int *a;

int main() {
  a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
}
```

Also please do not cast the return type of `malloc` in C. This is a common source of errors. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The top section (outside any function) allow only definitions, declarations and initialization but this line:

```
a=3;
```

is an assignment statment and the compiler considere it as a new declaration as you didn't specify any type for `a` that's why you get the error (`... no data type...`) and also as `a` is already declared as `int` you get the error (`...conflicting types...`)

Answer (score 0):

external and global variables must be defined exactly once outside of any function.